# Can I programatically (using the API or otherwise) get a link to a PDF version of an invoice

Tags: api

After I create an invoice in Jasmin using the API, can I get a link to a PDF version of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

Example: 
Getting the PDF for the document FA.2018.1

Method: GET
Address: {{url}}/api/{{tenant}}/{{organization}}/billing/invoices/{{company}}/FA/2018/1/print

Regards.